# How to use pattern comprehension to reduce DB hits comparing to collect

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been experimenting with pattern comprehensions for optimization but am getting even more confused.

This is my initial query:

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE 2000 <= m.year <= 2005 AND a.born.year >= 1980
RETURN a.name AS Actor, a.born AS Born,
collect(DISTINCT m.title) AS Movies ORDER BY Actor
```

When profiling I am got:

```
Cypher version: , planner: COST, runtime: PIPELINED. 41944 total db hits in 152 ms.
```

I tried rewriting it to:

```
profile MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.born.year >= 1980
// Add a WITH clause to create the list using pattern comprehension
with a
match (a)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m:Movie)
where 2000 <= m.year <= 2005
// filter the result of the pattern comprehension to return only lists with elements
// return the Actor, Born, and Movies
return a.name as Actor, a.born as Born, [(a)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m) | m.title]  as Movies
order by a
```

When profiling I got:

```
Cypher version: , planner: COST, runtime: PIPELINED. 47879 total db hits in 47 ms.
```

I tried another rewrite:

```
profile MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE a.born.year >= 1980
// Add a WITH clause to create the list using pattern comprehension
// filter the result of the pattern comprehension to return only lists with elements
// return the Actor, Born, and Movies
with a, [ (a)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m:Movie)  where 2000 <= m.year <= 2005 | m.title] as Movies
return a.name as Actor, a.born as Born, Movies
order by a
```

and when profiling got:

```
Cypher version: , planner: COST, runtime: PIPELINED. 59251 total db hits in 6 ms.
```

Each time, the performance is worse than the previous time. I can review the query plan to understand the differences. Is there a way to use pattern comprehension to actually reduce my DB hits compared to the initial query using a `collect` statement?

Comment: What is stored as the value of `a.born`? `a.born.year` does not seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the profile result on your last query; I tested it in Movie database and it worked well vs the orig query(46ms vs orig: 120db hits). Also, check if Actor.born.year has an index.

```
profile MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE 2000 <= m.released <= 2005 AND a.born >= 1980
RETURN a.name AS Actor, a.born AS Born,
collect(DISTINCT m.title) AS Movies ORDER BY Actor

planner: COST, runtime: PIPELINED. 120 total db hits in 9 ms


profile MATCH (a:Person)
WHERE  a.born >= 1980
RETURN a.name AS Actor, a.born AS Born,
[(a)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m:Movie) where 2000 <= m.released <= 2005 | m.title] AS Movies ORDER BY Actor

planner: COST, runtime: PIPELINED. 43 total db hits in 6 ms
```

Comment: Your second query does not expend the effort to get "distinct" movie titles, whereas the first query does. What happens if you remove the `DISTINCT` option from the first query?

Comment: both of your queries returns 0 rows...

Comment: btw, my experiments are ran in the sandbox from neo4j course, so anyone can try https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/cypher-aggregation/